# Converting char* to int after using strdup()

Tags: c++, c, pointers, type-conversion, strdup

Why after using `strdup(value)` `(int)value` returns you different output than before?
How to get the same output?

My short example went bad, please use the long one:
Here the full code for tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    //The First Part
    char *c = "ARD-642564";
    char *ca = "ARD-642564";

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << ca << std::endl;

//c and ca are equal
    std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)ca << std::endl;


    //The Second Part
    c = strdup("ARD-642564");
    ca = strdup("ARD-642564");

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << ca << std::endl;

//c and ca are NOT equal Why?
    std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)ca << std::endl;

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a good thing they're not equal? If they were, it wouldn't be much of a copy...

Comment: How to get the same output? Don't call strdup!

Comment: Are you sure that you need `(int)c`, not `atoi(c)`?\

Comment: In VC++ on 64 bit Windows, an `int` is 32 bits, but a pointer is 64 bits. Don't use `int` to store a pointer, as it's not guaranteed to fit.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that `c` and `ca` will be equal in the first part either. It is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because an array decays to a pointer in your case, you are printing a *pointer* (ie, on non-exotic computers, a memory address). There is no guarantee that a pointer fits in an `int`.

- In the first part of your code, `c` and `ca` don't have to be equal. Your compiler performs a sort of memory optimization (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/690252/1126268) for a full answer).
- In the second part, `strdup` allocates dynamically a string twice, such that the returned pointers are not equal. The compiler does not optimize these calls because he does not seem to control the definition of `strdup`.

In both cases, `c` and `ca` may not be equal.

Comment: Nice answer (and I like the *on non-exotic computers, a memory address*)

Answer (score 4):

> "The strdup() function shall return a pointer to **a new string**, which is a duplicate of the string pointed to by s1." [source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)

So it's quite understandable that the pointers differ.